# Complete orthonormal system of eigenfunctions for trace-class nonnegative operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, stochastic-analysis

In Da Prato/Zabczyk's book "Stochastic equations in inifinite dimension" I stumbled over the following paragraph:

Let $Q$ be a trace class nonnegative operator on a Hilbert space $U$.
[...]
Note that there exists a complete orthonormal system $\{e_k\}$ in $U$ and a bounded sequence of nonnegative real numbers $\{\lambda_k\}$ such that
$$ Qe_k = \lambda_k e_k.$$
Why is that?

Comment: This is just the spectral theorem for self-adjoint, compact operators. By the way, the sequence $(\lambda_k)$ is not only bounded but in $\ell^1$.

Comment: Reed and Simon has a good discussion/analysis of trace-class operators.